# Gnome 14.04 64-bit: HDMI Resolution 1920x1080 but displayed as 640x480

Tags: gnome, nvidia, display, resolution, hdmi

I just did a fresh install of ubuntu gnome 14.04 64 bit. During the installation I had my 22" screen attached to it and the image looked good and no problems at all.

**Problem**

I connected my tv with hdmi to my pc but (so just single monitor) the image is way to large. It displays like the resolution is set to 640x480. And even the tv show in the corner that it was actually displaying that resolution. So I tried to change it, but the resolution was already set to 1920x1080. When I set it to a lower resolution the image became even bigger. When I did a reboot the issue remains and the tv even now says that it is displaying at 1920x1080. The weird thing is that when I open firefox and I browse a website, the tex is really tiny like it is when the monitor does display 1920x1080

**Research**

- So I switched the xorg display driver to a nvidia one, still the same.
- Before I did the fresh install, the same pc was connected to the same tv with ubuntu unity, had resolution issues as well, but not like this

  - Switched to lighdm displaymanager, no difference.

**Screenshot**
[image: 1920x1080 resolution but all big]
As you can see the settings windows is extremly large, but the resolution is set to 1920x1080..

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 1):

And suddently it hit me, scaling factor! I set my scaling-factor to 1 which it fixes:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1
```

That fixed it! After that command, only my titles where still too big. But a reboot fixed that too.